# How to overwrite autoref in IEEE latex template for referencing sections

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing

I want to reproduce this behaviour:

[image]

```
\documentclass[journal, a4paper, 10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S}
\renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{\S}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{\S}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
\subsection{A subsection}\label{sec:subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\label{sec:subsubsection}
See \autoref{sec:section}, \autoref{sec:subsection} or \autoref{sec:subsubsection}.
\end{document}
```

In a double-column IEE template in latex overleaf. I tried to add the lines to my package and get this instead:

[image]

It is possible to overwrite IEE's style?

I don't like the approach of using

```
\S \ref{sec:*}
```

or

```
\S \autoref{sec:*}
```

## **EDIT**

Found that if calling `\usepackage[english]{babel}` before the `\usepackage{hyperref}` the `\S` symbol appears to be clickable. But if the hyperref package is called after the babel one, the renew commands do not work.

Comment: Looks like you lost a few lines at the beginning of your code. Please add them to make your question quite perfect. Thank you

Comment: The `IEEEtran` document class doesn't label section-, subsection-, and subsubsection-level header numbers as `1`, `1.1`, and `1.1.1`, respectively. Instead, they're labeled "Roman." (with the header string typeset in upright small-caps), "italic-Alpha." (with the header string typeset in italics), and "italic-arabic)" (with the header string typeset in italics as well)_. If you don't like this numbering style, you probably shouldn't employ the `IEEEtran` document class.

Comment: @MS-SPO The other lines are just the IEEEtran document-styling ones. What additional information do you need?

Comment: @Mico Hi! I think I haven't explained my question quite well. The problem is that when I try to reference a section. I want to add the ''\S'' symbol so it is within the hyperef environment (that is, it is also clickable). I am unsure how to do it as for now I can do it but the S symbol is not clickable and apart from that, even if I tweak the hyperref package it is not showing the symbol afterwards.

Comment: @YiQiangJi- You claim that the `\S` symbol isn't part of the clickable hypertarget is puzzling. Take, say, the following minimalist example: `\documentclass[twocolumn]{IEEEtran} \usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S} \begin{document} \section{A section}\label{sec:section} See \autoref{sec:section}. \end{document}`. When I compile it, the `\S` symbol is clearly part of the hypertarget. Please clarify what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @Mico I tried your snippet and it does exactly what I want to do. However, in my document, I cannot reproduce that behaviour somehow. I think it is maybe because I am using IEEEtrans.cls perhaps? Here is an example:

https://www.overleaf.com/read/grzwzgyddsmf

Comment: @YiQiangJi - The link you provided points to a document that employs the `IEEEtran` document class -- *not* the `IEEEtrans` class. The `IEEEtran` class is very well known. In contrast, I have never heard of the `IEEEtrans` class before you mentioned it just now, and I therefore have no idea what it may or may not do. The `IEEEtrans` class does not appear to be a part of the TeXLive distribution. Did you obtain `IEEEtrans.cls` from some place?

Comment: @YiQiangJi, please do the following test: create an empty latex file, copy your code into it, save and compile. If it doesn’t compile, then add lines of code, until it does AND shows your problem. Replace your posted code, finally. Thank you.

Comment: @Mico Hi! I have misspelt the IEEtran.cls (it is without the "s"). Then, it is the same package as you are mentioning. What can be the problem then?

Comment: @MS-SPO I am going to try it, however, it was so strange. since I deactivated all the packages and even deleted the IEEEtran.cls but it was still the same

Comment: @MS-SPO I managed to find the error with your approach. The problem is really hidden, I was first adding the following language package line ```\usepackage[english]{babel}``` before the ```hyperref```` package. In a normal document it works flawless but somehow, using the ```IEEEtran```, the renewcommand does not seem to work if it is called after loading the babel package. Is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: Great. // LaTeX is a complex set of macros. Most of the time this runs fine, but every now and than there is unwanted/unexpected interaction. That's one reason why we'd like to see complete enough code to avoid guessing. // I suggest to EDIT your question and to append your recent finding, e.g. after a P.S.-header. As I read it, it's not a solution (=answer) to a concrete problem (=question), is it?

Comment: @MS-SPO Sure! It's updated, I'll wait to see if anyone knows how to deal with this issue. Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using `babel` and, when you do so, the autoref names get set on the language hooks, in this case somewhere at begindocument. This is documented in `hyperref`'s manual, and all you have to do is set them on the language "extras":

```tex
\documentclass[journal, a4paper, 10pt]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\addto\extrasenglish{%
  \renewcommand{\sectionautorefname}{\S}%
  \renewcommand{\subsectionautorefname}{\S}%
  \renewcommand{\subsubsectionautorefname}{\S}%
}
\begin{document}
\section{A section}\label{sec:section}
\subsection{A subsection}\label{sec:subsection}
\subsubsection{A subsubsection}\label{sec:subsubsection}
See \autoref{sec:section}, \autoref{sec:subsection} or \autoref{sec:subsubsection}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: On a side note, you get to see how important the advice you received in the comments to provide a full MWE reproducing your problem is. Your original snippet did not include the document class, and did not include `babel`. It was hard to guess what was going on. With all elements in place, it was trivial to diagnose.

Comment: Thanks for the help and the advice. I will definitely keep it in mind!